# How can I compact a collection in my IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB deployment?

Tags: database, mongodb, ibm-cloud

I have a deployment of IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB. I want to compact the collections in my database to save disk space and increase performance. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Mongo shell CLI.

To connect to your IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB instances using the Mongo shell you will need:

- The password for the `admin` user
- The CA certificate, downloaded and stored locally as a file
- A set of host names and ports

See the instructions on how to obtain these in the [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-mongodb?topic=databases-for-mongodb-connection-strings&interface=ui)

The connection string contains a list of the 3 nodes that make up your Highly Available cluster. You will need to target each node separately and compact the copy of the collection on every node.

To connect to a node, use the following Mongo shell command:

```bash
mongosh -u admin -p <your_password> --ssl --sslCAFile path/to/file  --authenticationDatabase admin --host <hostname:port>

# Current Mongosh Log ID:   xxxx
#Connecting to:     mongodb://<credentials>@hostname:port/?#directConnection=true&authSource=admin&tls=true&tlsCAFile=file&appName=mongosh+2.1.1
#For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/
#Enterprise replset [direct: secondary] test>
```

Now target the database where your collection is:

```bash
use mydb
```

Finally, issue the `compact` command for each collection you want to compact:

```bash
db.runCommand({compact:"mycollection"})
```

Be aware that this command will fail if you try to compact a collection in the current Primary node. You may add a `force` flag to the command if you want to proceed regardless:

```bash
db.runCommand({compact:"catalog", force:true})
```

The MongoDB [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/compact/) suggest that this does not block CRUD operations while compacting.